# Excel freeze while entering a value into textbox within the userform

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, freeze

I have an Excel user form with two text boxes. When I try to enter a value in one of them, Excel freezes and stops working. But the strange thing is that this works on other computers in the office which are exactly the same.
It is a really simple user form with two text boxes, set to change, and one button.
I'm not sure if it's because of Excel, maybe something in Windows.
I have Excel 2016 and Windows 10 on my computer.

Has anyone had this problem?

```
Private Sub applyCommandButton_Click()
    Range("A3").Value = TextBox1.Value & " " & TextBox2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Range("A2").Value = TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Have you tried to step through the code? Does the freeze happen while typing or when switching to the other box?

Comment: Hello Tom and thanks for your time. I tried to go through the code. It only allows me to type the first character and when I try to type the next one, Excel freezes. So it happens while typing.

Comment: Do you perhaps have many formulas in your Workbook that reference the cell that is being updated ("A1" or "A2" depending on which TextBox is being typed into ... noting that you are not specifying a particular Workbook or Worksheet)? Maybe try turning off automatic calculations (Formulas > Calculation Options > Manual) and see if performance improves?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the suggestion. There are no formulas in the worksheet. It works perfectly fine on the other computers in the office. We tried reinstalling the Microsoft Office but it's the same. We had the same problem in the past on two computers and we reinstalled windows on both, but in the end, the problem was solved on one computer and not on the other. I really don't understand. Is it possible that Windows has some settings that interfering Excel?